# json4s JValue expected (String,String) given

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

Using Scala and json4s (Maybe Im missing a golden fish library or something)

I am trying to add some list (or array) of strings to a JSON so in the end looks like:

```
{"already":"here",..."listToAdd":["a","b",c"]}
```

The fact is that I already have the String in a JObject and the list of strings in an Array[String] (but it could be changed to List if needed). So I followed the docat [json4s.org](http://json4s.org) which states that:

```
Any seq produces JSON array.

scala> val json = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> compact(render(json))

res0: String = [1,2,3]
```

---

```
Tuple2[String, A] produces field.

scala> val json = ("name" -> "joe")

scala> compact(render(json))

res1: String = {"name":"joe"}
```

And when trying it, it gives:

```
Error:(15, 28) type mismatch;
found   : (String, String)
required: org.json4s.JValue
    which expands to)  org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
    println(compact(render(idJSON)))
```

Using Scala 2.11.4
      Json4s 3.2.11 (Jackson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to additionally import some implicit conversion methods:

```
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
```

These will convert the Scala objects into the library's Json AST.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that one!